# Can I use a div inside a list item?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, html-lists

Why is the following code valid when I am using a `<div>` inside a `<li>`?

```
<ul>
    <li class="aschild">
        <div class="nav">Test</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the problem that you have when you have this code in a page?

Comment: @Vimal Basdeo
: Intriguing: a question about why you don't have a problem.

Comment: @Vimal Basdeo: Perhaps you should begin by explaining why you think that it **should** be a problem.

Comment: No problem at all.It displays correctly but as  googled I found that I cannot use a div inside a list so I just want to confirm if it's ok to use a div inside a list

Comment: The question is valid, bashing and downvoting the OP is quite meaningless in this case. As I guess, it is based on a misunderstanding and as such, it would be beneficial to be answered correctly (now I see though that @Jawad's link is an exact duplicate).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes you can use a div inside a li and it will validate.

```
<!ELEMENT li %Flow;>
<!ENTITY % Flow "(#PCDATA | %block; | form | %inline; | %misc;)*">
<!ENTITY % block     "p | %heading; | div | %lists; | %blocktext; | fieldset | table">
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what that block of code above actually means? Thanks.

Comment: @yochannah: That's just the DTD. It is irrevelant now since HTML5 is no longer DTD based. http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd

Comment: What is HTML5 based on now?

Comment: HTML5 is based on schemas.

Answer (score 51):

Inside a `<li>` you can have anything you could naturally put inside a `<div>`. They are no different in this sense.

It should be valid in HTML4, XHTML and HTML5 as well.

This is **NOT** valid though (so the sources you found about "no divs in lists" could refer to this situation):

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <div></div>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**So:** Lists (`ul`, `ol`) can only have `li`s as their children. But `li`s can have anything as their children.

Comment: Why is it not valid. Or more specific, where does it says that it is not vallid. The DTD allows it?

Comment: @Jawad Lists can only have `li`s as their children. But `li`s can have anything as their children. I think this is where the OP has mistaken one for the other.

Answer (score 18):

Because `<li>` is a block element, not an inline element like `<span>` or `<a>`.

Answer (score 12):

An `<li>` is a block element, and will work perfectly fine with other block elements inside.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. As much as you want.

Comment: I am convinced.

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look with your developer tools and inspect katespade website's code you will find that you can add as many div inside a Li tag but you cannot add the  tag as a child in  `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

```
        <ul> 

    <li> <div class="example1> 

<span>lorem ipsum </span>
</div> </li>
    <li> </li>

     </ul>
```

here is an example on this katespade's web app

[Katespade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzmR4.png)