# Inline block not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, display

I am trying to have a `li` element and a `div` be "inline", but right now the `div` text keeps being put right below the `li` element. I'm using `display: inline block` and jQuery as below:

```
$('#list').append(
   '<div class="spanish">\
      <li>'+new_task+'</li>\
      <div>Test</div>\
   </div>');


.spanish {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: please provide more of your code, including the rest of the HTML and CSS  markup.

Comment: The **only** allowed parent elements for `li` are `ul` and `ol`. **You are creating invalid HTML.** You cannot have an `li`  as a child of a `div`.

Comment: Following up on @connexo's comment: you cannot have an `li` as a child of a `div`, but you can have a `div` as a child of an `li`.

Comment: So instead of appending something like `<div><li>${new_task}</li> <div>Test</div></div>`, you could append something like `<li>${new_task} <span>Test</span></li>`. In this case, a `span` may be better than a `div` for your purposes, since a `span` is an inline element, whereas a `div` is a block element.

Answer (score 2):

As @ValeriySiestov mentioned, `div` is a block element, and `li` is a block element as well.

One way to fix your problem is to change the structure of the html you are appending, so it is a `span` element within the `li` element.

Note that list elements (i.e. `ul`s or `ol`s) can only have `li`s as their children, but `li`s can have anything as their children. Reference: [Can I use a div inside a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449772/can-i-use-a-div-inside-a-list-item)

Assuming you have an unordered list with id #list, you can append a new list item to it like so:

```js
var new_task = "walk the dog"

var li_string = `<li>${new_task}: <span>Test</span></li>`

 $('#list').append(li_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
<li>make bed</li>
<li>brush teeth</li>
</ul>
```

Note the variable `new_task` is being interpolated within the string of html being appended to the list using template literals.

Template literals syntax:

`string text ${expression} string text`

Comment: op isn't talking about appending new item to list. The problem is that the elements isn't appearing inline. fyi I'm not the down voter

Comment: You are not fixing the invalid HTML OP creates.

Comment: @connexo added note referencing list elements only having `li`s as their children, including a reference link, and updated my `li_string` variable.

Answer (score 1):

div - is a block (display: block) element by default. It stretches to 100% of parent's width
li - is an item of the list (display: list-item) and also stretches to 100% of parent's width

If you want to change this behaviour, you need to add to div and li another display value, like this

```
.spanish div, .spanish li {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
.spanish div, .spanish li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In your code, you use

inslide , this is not actualy right, this is not critical, it will work, but

must be inside

Answer (score 1):

It seems from you code. You want to print div below li. There are few things to note:

1. Li should always come inside UL or OL tag. You current code  is semantically wrong.
2. There can be only Li come as sibling of Li. No any other tag (You are using div)
3. For position use css.

Please check below answer if its helpful to you.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
var new_task = "<div class='row'>row</div>";

$('#list').append(
 '<div class="spanish">\
<ul>\
    <li>'+new_task+'<div class="sub-row">Test</div></li>\
</ul>\
 </div>');
});
```

```css
.row {
 display: inline;
clear:both:
widht:100%
}
.sub-row {
display:inline;
clear:both;
margin-left:2px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: I want row and test to be on the same line, your code still puts it below

Comment: fixed the solution. You have to just change css to display: inline on couple of places.